# What is the diffrence between these definitions for `async inline methods`?

Tags: dart, async-await

We are able to define an `async inline method` in different ways, Is there any difference in the result or under the hood?

```dart
1. 
Future<void> counter() async => await Future<void>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => print('Result'),
    );

2.
Future<void> counter() async => Future<void>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => print('Result'),
    );

3.
Future<void> counter() => Future<void>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => print('Result'),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timing, if anything.

The `async => await` version waits for the delayed future created by `Future.delayed` to complete before returning, then it completes the returned future.
The `async =>` version should do precisely the same, since the await is implicit in the return.
The `=>` version returns the future created by `Future.delayed` directly.

In either case, the returned future will be completed after the 5 second duration has passed. It may or may not go through an extra intermediate microtask.